# Are there any penalties for ignoring a shot down UFO?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I'm at a point in the game where I really don't need the materials from downed UFOs. I know there are penalties for not shooting down UFOs, but are there any penalties for shooting it down and then declining to assault it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no penalties.

The panic will not change, and that is all that matters.

You will still get an A on your council report aswell.

I have confirmed this on Ironman Impossible, as I choose to ignore a downed battleship, and there was no negative outcome.